DECLARE is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ALTER,
I am new to SQL
I was trying this assignment and wanted to calculate total duration of pandemic in months, for which I used DECLARE, but it shows error of not in valid position, what is the issue here?
I am using MySQL Workbench
SELECT *
FROM corona_analysis.corona_dataset
WHERE Province is null
OR Country is null
OR Latitude is null
OR Longitude is null
OR Date is null
OR Confirmed is null
OR Deaths is null
OR Recovered is null;


SELECT COUNT(*) total_rows
FROM corona_analysis.corona_dataset;

SELECT MIN(Date) AS start_date,
       MAX(Date) AS end_date
FROM corona_analysis.corona_dataset;


DECLARE @start_date DATE='2020-01-22',
DECLARE @end_date DATE='2021-06-13';
SELECT (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @start_date, @end_date)) AS number_of_months;


How can I rectify this issue?

It looks like you're mixing up MySQL and MS SQL Server. To be sure which you're actually using, please include the full and exact error message in your question. Also, you have a comma after your first DECLARE. Either keep the comma and remove the second declare DECLARE @x DATE = 'FOO', @y DATE = 'BAR'; or use a semi-colon DECLARE @x DATE = 'FOO'; DECLARE @y DATE = 'BAR';

In MySQL, the DECLARE statement is used within a stored procedure, function, or a block of code. It cannot be used directly within a standard SQL script like how you are attempting in your query. Instead, you can use variables in a different way or simply use the dates directly in your DATEDIFF calculation.
Without using DECLARE you can do like this.
SELECT MIN(Date) AS start_date,
       MAX(Date) AS end_date
INTO @start_date, @end_date
FROM corona_analysis.corona_dataset;

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, @start_date, @end_date) AS number_of_months;

Or you can directly use the below query.
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, MIN(Date), MAX(Date) ) AS number_of_months FROM corona_analysis.corona_dataset;

